# Displaying multiple data in one column

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm making a website that displays grades.

I have 3 tables in my database.

First database is `master_list` and its table

```
student_ID, 
firstname, 
middlename, 
lastname, 
birthday, 
age, 
sex, 
address, 
contacts,
```

Second table: `section`

```
student_section_id, 
school_year, 
Section_name,
```

Third table: `subjects`

```
subject_id, 
subject_name, 
firstgrading, 
secondgrading, 
thirdgrading, 
fourthgrading, 
average_grade, 
remarks,
```

and here is my code.

```
 <?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Error connecting to database: ".mysql_error());


    mysql_select_db("capstone") or die(mysql_error());
    ?>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Search results</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    $query = $_GET['query']; 


    $min_length = 0;


    if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ 

        $query = htmlspecialchars($query); 


        $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);


        $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT firstname, middlename, lastname 
            ,section_name, school_year
            ,subject_name, firstgrading, secondgrading, thirdgrading, fourthgrading, average_grade
            FROM master_list,section,subjects
            WHERE (student_id LIKE '".$query."')") or die(mysql_error());



        if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ 


            while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){


                echo "<p><h3>".$results['firstname']." ".$results['middlename']." ".$results['lastname']."</h3><br />"
                .$results['section_name']." ".$results['school_year']."<br />"
                .$results['subject_name']." ".$results['firstgrading']." ".$results['secondgrading']." ".$results['thirdgrading']." ".$results['fourthgrading']." ".$results['average_grade']."
                </p>";

            }

        }
        else{ 
            echo "No results";
        }

    }
    else{ 
        echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
    }?>

</body>
</html>
```

and here is the result:

```
Vince Monarca Carreon


Grade 10 2016 - 2017
English 4 80 84 83 82 82

Vince Monarca Carreon


Grade 10 2016 - 2017
Filipino 4 90 91 88 89 90
```

The name also loops and what I want is the name should not repeat. Like this

```
Vince Monarca Carreon


Grade 10 2016 - 2017

English 4 80 84 83 82 82

Filipino 4 90 91 88 89 90
```

Comment: Is this this the minimal amount of code required for this question? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: at least put some effort to format your question and make it redable

Comment: Noted. im new here

Comment: The subjects table should not have repeated columns. Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ac39e4/3

Comment: the `mysql_` code library that you're using is end-of-life. It was deprecated a long time ago and then removed entirely in PHP7. It's known to be insecure and does not support things like prepared statements and parameterised queries which greatly reduce the risk of SQL Injection attacks. Using your existing code there's a strong chance your data could be hacked or corrupted by a malicious user or bot. Switch to using a supported library (`mysqli_` or `PDO` are the options) and get used to using parameterised prepared statements. You can find lots of examples online.